# Angular-ui-calendar refresh after next/prev

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm beginning with angular-ui-calendar.

At this moment all basic operations are working ( create events, update events, delete events and show all events from Web API ).

But I have one problema : from the initial view ( loaded with some events )  when I change the month ( with NEXT button ) the view is not updated and using the BACK button moving the view to the previous month, the view remains empty with none of the events displayed when the page is loaded.

Can anyone tell me what events are fired when the calendar navigate between months ? I thon I need use these events to refresh the calendar.

Thank you

Comment: /* event source that calls a function on every view switch */
        `$scope.eventsF = function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
            var s = new Date(start).getTime() / 1000;
            var e = new Date(end).getTime() / 1000;
            var m = new Date(start).getMonth();
            var events = $scope.events
            callback(events);
        };` also while creating the new event push event object with `stick: true`